# Passing arguments from Panels to Views in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, panels, views

I'm attempting to use [The "It's Common Sense" guide to passing arguments from Panels to Views](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/04/passing-arguments-from-panel-to-views.html) but I'm running into an issue at step 7:

> At the Configure Panel pane form, make sure you choose "No context" as the Taxonomy Term, check the Send Arguments box. In the Arguments field there, type in %term

That sounds very reasonable... but I can't find any such checkbox.

I tried just muddling through the tutorial without doing that step, but it doesn't work. I end up with a weird, long URL and it just redirects back to the root of my site.

For context, I'm trying to create an archive of nodes by year. When there's no arguments, I get a list of years from 2009-2012. If I click, say, 2009 (coming from a page with path `/?q=archives`), I get the following URL:

`/?date[value]=&date[min]=&date[max]=&date_filter_1[value]=2012-11-14 00%3A00%3A00&date_filter_1[min]=2012-11-14 00%3A00%3A00&date_filter_1[max]=`

I'm hoping for something like, `/?q=archives/2009` instead. (Not that that currently works either.)

Comment: Are you using Views 2 or Views 3 on your site?  I am not positive, but I think that matters in this case.

Comment: I'm using Views 2.